# crazy continuous error:[Socket error occurred: xxx: Network is unreachable] when network is not available

Tags: apache-curator

error occurs when network is not available, but it always try to reconnect and log error,
maybe anywhere to set the reconnection inteval or attempt times?
I guess it is about the curator watcher,but I indeed find nothing in curator docs or codes,
can somebody help me?
Thanks for everything.

curator version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-recipes</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

logs:

```
    2020-08-09 10:27:14.684  INFO 91181 --- [26.102.59:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server 10.226.102.59/10.226.102.59:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-08-09 10:27:14.684 ERROR 91181 --- [26.102.59:2181)] o.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO   : Unable to open socket to 10.226.102.59/10.226.102.59:2181
2020-08-09 10:27:14.684  INFO 91181 --- [26.102.59:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Socket error occurred: 10.226.102.59/10.226.102.59:2181: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: What version of Curator are you using? Can you post the log?

Comment: @Randgalt, Hi Randgalt, I just updated the question above.Hope the advanced suggestions.

Comment: It cannot connect to the address. Looks normal to me. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it continuously print the error log that the network is unreachable, maybe should have some exponential reconnection policy or reconnection with interval  time in case of the error log cannot stop.